# MySQL incorrect result on group by

Tags: php, mysql

I am counting unique ip visits for user account. I am getting different result on checking total visits vs grouped user account visits

My table structure is like this

```
id     userid     userip     status    date
1      xxxx       11111      1        unix timestamp
2      yyyy       11122      1        unix timestamp
3      zzzz       11133      1        unix timestamp
4      cccc       11144      1        unix timestamp
```

I am doing query like this

```
$date1 = strtotime("yesterday midnight");
$date2 = strtotime("today midnight");

SELECT `userid`, COUNT(DISTINCT `userip`) AS `total` FROM `stats` 
WHERE (`date` >= $date1 AND `date` < $date2) AND `status`=1
```

This gives result as 5644

But when I group by `userid` result is different

```
$date1 = strtotime("yesterday midnight");
$date2 = strtotime("today midnight");

SELECT `userid`, COUNT(DISTINCT `userip`) AS `total` FROM `stats` 
WHERE (`date` >= $date1 AND `date` < $date2) AND `status`=1 GROUP BY `userid`

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $total=$total+$row['total'];
}
```

This gives result as 6312

Please see why there is different result on group by

Thanks

**EDIT**

Result is correct if I don't count `DISTINCT`

Comment: please add you expected output  in your question

Comment: have you done join in your main query ?

Comment: @knowledge.... no joins

Comment: @NishantNair for give data result should be 4 for both queries, live data is giving different result and I can't tell where the result is in correct whether on total or on group.

Comment: what is the count for it is total rows or ip count ?

Comment: @knowledge.... its unique ip count in given date

Comment: it will give user wise count am i right ?

Comment: Yes when using group by `userid` other wise it will return result for all users

Answer (score 0):

its obvious that the `count` wont match as in your first query you have used distinct with count now the rows fetched is `5644`.

Which may have count with the values like `2,3,4,5` so if you need the same count as `group by` you need to add all the count column which will be same as your group by query

if you need unique users the use below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `userip`  AS `userip` FROM `stats` 
WHERE (`date` >= $date1 AND `date` < $date2) AND `status`=1
```

For user with unique ip

```
SELECT userid,userip from stats GROUP BY userip HAVING COUNT(*) >=1
```

Comment: you are assigning value of ip count to userid?

Comment: sorry it was spelling mistake I was not assigning any value

Comment: I need user account `userid` as well how to do it